# Portable, Open-Source Java Web Server Recommendations?

Tags: java, http, apache

Does anyone know a good Java Web Server framework that I can be bundled into an executable that can be run from the command line?

Basically something that allows me to develop a program that runs on a port via HTTP and for the user requires these installation steps:

1. Install Java.
2. Download my executable tool.
3. Run it from the command line.

Any idea if any of the popular frameworks like Java Spring or Grails offer support for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)?

From the Jetty site:

> Jetty provides an Web server and [javax.servlet](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) container, plus support
>   for Web Sockets, OSGi, JMX, JNDI, JASPI, AJP and many other
>   integrations. These components are open source and available for
>   commercial use and distribution.

Details on embedding Jetty can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html).

Answer (score 2):

My favorite embedded http server for Java is Jetty
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

Spring can run on top of jetty or any other embedded server. It doesn't contain any code to be a server itself.

It's very simple to integrate and setup and runs quite efficiently for a small amount of users (have not tested it on more than that).